# ant ask user which target to call if not specified

Tags: ant

i have this ant `build.xml` file with 3 targets in it:

`target1`, `target2` and `target3`.

If the user simply runs `ant` and not an explicit `ant target1` or something like that, i want to prompt the user asking which target he would like to call.

Remember, the user should only be prompted for this only if he doesnt explicitly call a target while running `ant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use the `input` task provided by ant and make it your **default** target.

```
<input
message="Please enter Target ID (1,2 or 3):"
validargs="1,2,3"
addproperty="targetID"
/>
```

Use the value of this property to decide which target to execute.

From the ant documentation:

> **message** : The Message which gets displayed to the user during the build run.
>
> **validargs**: Comma separated String containing valid input arguments. If set, input task will reject any input not defined here.
>   You may pass any arguments according to your needs.
>
> **addproperty** : The name of a property to be created from input.Behaviour is equal to property task which means that existing
>   properties cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 4):

Ant is not a programming language, it's a dependency matrix language. There's a big difference between the two.

In a program language, you can specify the absolute order of sequence. Plus, you have a lot more flexibility in doing things. In Ant, you don't specify the execution order. You specify various short *how to build this* steps and then specify their dependencies. Ant automatically will figure out the execution order needed.

It's one of the hardest things for developers to learn about Ant. I've seen too many times when developers try to force execution order and end up executing the same set of targets dozens of times over and over. I recently had a build her that took almost 10 minutes to build, and I rewrote the `build.xml` to produce the same build in under 2 minutes.

You could use `<input/>` to get the user input, then use `<exec>` or `<java>` to execute another Ant process to execute the requested target. However, this breaks the way Ant is suppose to work.

The default target should be the default target that developers would want to execute on a regular basis while they program. It should not *clean* the build. It should not run 10 minutes of testing. It should compile any changed files, and rebuild the war or jar. That's what I want about 99% of the time. The whole process takes 10 seconds.

I get really, really pissed when someone doesn't understand this. I hate it when I type `ant` and I get directions on how to execute my build. I get really irritated when the default target cleans out my previous compiles. And, I get filled with the deadly desire to pummel the  person who wrote the damn build file with a large blunt object if I am prompted for something. That's because I will run Ant, do something else while the build happens, then come back to that command window when I think the build is done. Nothing makes me angrier to come back to a *build* only to find out it's sitting there waiting for me to tell it which target.

If you really, really need to do this. Use a shell script called `build.sh`. Don't futz with the `build.xml`to do this because that affects development.

What you really need to do is teach everyone how to use Ant:

- Ant will list user executable targets when you type in `ant -p`. This will list all targets, and their descriptions. If a target doesn't have a description, it won't list it. This is great for internal targets that a user shouldn't execute on their own. (For example, a target that merely does some sort of test to see if another target should execute). To make this work, make sure your targets have descriptions. I get angry when the person who wrote the Ant file puts a description for some minor target that I don't want, but forgets the description of the target I do want (like compile). Don't make David angry. You don't want to make David [angry](http://www.kennethjohnson.us/HulkOutList.html).
- Use default target names for your group. That way, I know what targets do what across the entire project instead of one project using `BUILD` vs. `build-programs` vs. `Compile` vs `build-my-stuff` vs. `StuffBuild`. We standardized on [Maven lifecycle names](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) names. They're documented and there's no arguments or debates.
- Do not use `<ant/>` or `<antcall>` to enforce build order. Do not divide your `build.xml` into a dozen separate `build.xml` programs. All of these probably break Ant's ability to build a target dependency matrix. Besides, many Ant tools that show dependency hierarchy in a build and they can't work across multiple build files.
- Do not wrap your builds inside a shell script. If you do this, you're probably not understanding how builds work.
- The build should not update any files in my working directory that were checked out by me. It shouldn't polute my working directory with all sorts of build artifacts spread out all over the place. It shouldn't do anything outside of the working directory (except maybe do some sort of deploy, but only when I run the deploy target). In fact, all build processing should take place in a sub-directory INSIDE my working directory. A `clean` should merely delete this one directory. Sometimes, this is called `build`, sometimes `dist`. I usually call it `target` because I've adopted Maven naming conventions.
- Your build script should be a build script. It shouldn't do checkouts or updates -- at least not automatically. I know that if you use CruiseControl as a continuous build process, you have to have update and checkout functionality inside your build.xml. It's one of the reasons I now use Jenkins.

Sorry about this answer not necessarily being the one you're looking for. You didn't really state what you're doing with Ant. If you're doing builds, don't do what you're trying to do. If you're writing some sort of program, use a real programming language and not Ant.

An Ant build should typically finish in under a minute or two, and redoing a build because you changed a file shouldn't take more than 30 seconds. This is important to understand because I want to encourage my developers to build with Ant, and to use the same targets that my Jenkins server uses. That way, they can test out their build the same way my Jenkins server will do the official build.

Comment: David, this is easily the best article i have read on Ant! I recently started learning(sort of) Ant just a couple weeks ago, and i honestly say i needed something like this. Thanks for that.

It's kind of hard to describe what i'm dong but lets just say its not very much unlike a install/uninstall thingie! I thought maybe asking the user what he wants to do if not specified, made sense! I'll put in some thought into it, but thanks a ton!!